# Passing data between TableView and Viewcontroller

Tags: ios

I am trying to pass data between UItableview to a UIViewController containing a Tableview

Comment: Have you checked what values you're getting for `[object objectForKey:@"picutes"]` and `[tableView viewWithTag:1]` at the appropriate points to make sure they're what you expect.

Comment: Either put in breakpoints and step through with the debugger to look at the variables as you reference them, or use `NSLog()` to print them to the console.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set an `NSArray` to your `PFImageView`

```
_imageView.image=[_arrayimages copy];
```

You better set  `UIImage` to your `_imageView.image` :)

An example:

```
if ([_arrayimages count] > 0) {
   _imageView.image = [_arrayimages objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Same like you do in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :

```
imageView.image=[self.arrayimages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: the if statement is going in my viewdidLoad

Comment: I got u man, But still, It doesn't make it ok to set array as an image.

Comment: i did but still no images are loaded

Comment: dont you think i need a query to get the selected animal images

Comment: Do u have any images in your arrayimages ?

Comment: technically all my images is in parse that  so then i used that line of code to assign my imges to the array :
    destviewcontroller.arrayimages=[object objectForKey:@"picutes"];

Comment: parse? Do u mead parse server?

Comment: yeah sorry i'm so frustated about this i am trying to solve this problem for a while now

Comment: Chill man, I want to help u. U must understand that what u asked has nothing with the fact that your images in your parse server. If you want to get your remote images u must to make a HTTP get request. U must get your image before u try to set it.

Comment: so basically i need to query the pictures first then set to arrayimages right

Comment: i am not going to lie to you i dont really know how to use this method AFNetworking

Comment: I am using the Parse server i dont think it allows you to do that

Comment: Basically before i was trying to use a collectionview but i didnt know how to "create an Comment Button under the images" but that is why i am using a TableviewController

Comment: It's a simple HTTP get request, every server (with rest API) will do so.

Comment: i will read it and also do you know how create Comment or Likes Button under a tableview

Comment: U need to be more specific, there is plenty of ways to do so

Comment: lol i wish i been looking for days lol but still i have the idea like i create the footerview then delcare the Button : UIButton *button=(UIButton *)[footerview viewWithtags:1]; then declare a method to for the button but i am stuck here